# Derivations of special rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Consider $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and let $A$ be any finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}_p$ algebra without zero divisors (and maybe without $1$). Now we can look on $A$ as on a ring $A_{\mathbb{Z}}$ (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}$- algebra) and let $M_p$ be any [$p$-torsion bimodule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624924/definition-of-p-torsion-module) over $A_{\mathbb{Z}}$. Is it true that the set of [derivations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)) $\textbf{Der}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A_{\mathbb{Z}}, M_p) = 0$?

Comment: I think I can prove that for every $d\in\textbf{Der}_{\mathbb{Z}}(A_{\mathbb{Z}}, M_p)$, $d(A_{\mathbb{Z}}^2) = 0$. To prove it consider any $a, b\in A_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and let $n$ be a natural number, such that $p^nd(a) = p^nd(b) = 0$ (it is possible, because $M_p$ is $p$-torsion). So let $a'$, $b'$ be elements from $A_{\mathbb{Z}}$, such that $p^na' = a, p^nb'=b$ (it is possible because $A$ is $\mathbb{Q}_p$ algebra). So $d(ab) = ad(b)+d(a)b = p^na'd(b)+d(a)p^nb' = a'd(p^nb)+d(p^na)b' = 0$.